# How do i use the TrimToSize method on a 2d Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I had a 2D array I converted to an ArrayList of Arraylists

I now have an Arraylist of ArrayLists which contains

```
[[1,3,4,0,0,0][0,2,5,0,0,0] .... ]
```

I would like to use the TrimToSize method on the inner arraylists to remove the values that have been initialised to zero by default ( the values at the end of each arraylist)

Is this possible or is there an alternative method of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: As I understand things, `.trimToSize()` doesn't work to trim out 0's from an ArrayList of Integer. The `.size()` of the List vs the length of the backing array is all that matters, regardless of what they contain (even if they contain nulls).

Comment: `trimToSize()` won't remove objects with value 0 from the list. You have to iterate manually and remove those elements.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way: trimToSize will not shorten the content, but remove the elements that were preallocated and not used.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your input

Comment: How do you know that these 0's are initialised by default not by user ?

Comment: In this example, If I have an array of length 6 and I have added the numbers 1,3,4  then the rest of the numbers will be zero by default as when you initialise an Integer Array in Java it's default value is 0. When I then convert to arraylists it keep those numbers that were originally initialised to 0. In the second example I have inserted the values of 0,2,5 into the array.